# Main Activity not opening

Tags: android

My app seems to start up properly, with the splash screen and stuff. But when it sleeps for 6 secs and when it supposed to get into the main activity the app crashes any help please?

Here is me code (android.intent.action1.MAINACTIVIVTY, the "action" was purposely changed to "action1")

```
package com.hellhogone.multitools;

import com.hellhogone.multitools.R;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    MediaPlayer yo = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.smusic); 
    yo.start(); 

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(6000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent h1 = new Intent("android.intent.action1.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(h1); 
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start(); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish(); 
}



}
```

Comment: this is a rough guess...have you registered your next activity in manifest...if not just registered it there...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start an activity from another thread than the UI thread. To avoid this problem you can use [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) :

```
    }finally{
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent h1 = new Intent("android.intent.action1.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(h1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It works perfectly with the other activities, just not with the main activity.